# Run configuration with command line program in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: ember.js, intellij-idea, command-line

I would like to add a configuration inside IntelliJ so that I can run it from the Run context menu (there is included Node.JS launcher but I couldn't find a "Command Line configuration launcher")

Also, is it possible to run the command line terminal as Administrator if ran from Windows ?

The command I would like to run is `ember serve`

Thanks for the help.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the steps:

1. Go to Run/Edit Configurations...
2. Add a new one for "Javascript Debug"
3. Fill `Name` with the name you want for the configuration, fill the `URL` with `http://localhost:4200` and pick the browser you prefer
4. Then, in the second white box, add an external tool by clicking in the green plus button and selecting the option `Run External tool`
5. Add a new one clicking on the green plus button and fill the following fields: in `Name` the name you want for the external tool, in `Program` write `ember` (it's the command you are going to run), in `Parameters` write `server` or `s` as the options for the command and in `Working directory` write `$ProjectFileDir$` if it's not written already to run it in the folder in which you are working with.

[image: external tool config]

With all this, you should only need to press the play button and it should run and open the browser automatically with a tab directing to localhost:4200, where your `ember server` is running.

EDIT: I'm not using it on windows so I'm not sure if it will run the command as administrator. Probably running Intellij using "Run as Administrator" will do the job.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved the day :-) 
This is Javascript Debug because it's opening a browser.
But could I run any other program in the same way, without needing to specify a URL ?
Thanks

Comment: @cyberjoac I haven't explored it that much but I think it should be possible.

Comment: @HenryVonfire: Hi, i have similar problem. Tried running `IntelliJ` as admin. When i try to run, it says `Error running 'Ember Server': Cannot run program "ember" (in directory "D:\dev\Node_JS\ember-test"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`. But if i run `ember serve` from terminal, it works fine. What i am missing? Also i installed `ember-cli` with `-g`.

Comment: @RajkishanSwami: Make sure you include the full path before ember in the _Tool Settings -> Program_ configuration. My guess is IDEA is not considering the PATH environment variable at this step.